# Print all group footer rows on the next page if they won't all fit on the first page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have a purchase order form in SSRS. It's grouped on the Purchase Order number. There are four rows in the group footer for totals.

Is there a way to keep all rows in the footer together? That is, if all of them won't fit on the page, that all of them will be printed on the next page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways of attempting to accomplish this. Using the KeepTogether property for the selected rows or the entire group

[image]

Or when SSRS inevitably doesn't do what you want it to do, you can do the ole Rectangle and Textbox trick. Insert a row above the subtotal that is also a group footer. Then insert a rectangle. Once you do this, you can insert a bunch of text boxes and move them freely around and structure them in the same way you had them formatted the 4 separate rows. It would look something like the below. With this way SSRS couldn't split the row onto multiple pages because its all in the same row. For insurance purposes check the KeepTogether box for this row as well.

[image]

Comment: I tried the KeepTogether -- didn't accomplish much. But the rectangle in one row should work.

Comment: @jim31415 Hope that solution worked okay. Let me know after you try it if it still doesn't work. Want to make sure my answer is correct.